# Converting string to object

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to convert a string that was created by Object.ToString() back to the original object i.e:

```
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent event) {     
                appendLog(event.toString());
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);      
            }
```

appent log will log every keyevent as a string in a new line. After logging i would like to run the logged keyevents

Is it possible to convert the string logged keyevents to a KeyEvent object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the `toString()` contains all the necessary event information. If it's just a hash code, of course not. If the relevant info is available, you'd need to parse it, and use one of the `KeyEvent` constructors, and hope there's nothing internally that isn't reflected in the `toString`. Seems sketchy to me.

If you need to store it, it's `Parcelable`, that might help.

You still have the event in the snippet you show, without an actual usecase it's hard to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: i added the function, im logging the keyevents in a text file then i would like to read the keyevents from the text file and "reply" them

Comment: @MikeG Why? are you trying to build a robot? Those already exist.

Comment: Im trying to build recorder that records user events like clicks, movement, keystrokes etc... Im not sure what a robot is, if what im trying to do already exists can you provide some links. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. The String won't contain enough information to reconstruct the original object. Of course, if you *do* encode enough information in the String returned by toString(), you may reconstruct the object - for instance, you can serialize an object to an XML - a String, and from that XML rebuild the object that originated it. Take a look at [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible but probably not the way you're thinking. In order to do this all the data related to KeyEvent would have to converted to text form, then parsed and a new KeyEvent created. An additional problem is KeyEvent lacks setters to recreate the internal state so to complete the return conversion you must create a sub class or find a way to use Parcelable to convert the parsed string.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to replay keyboard and mouse events then you should look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

You will need to listen for all events and record all of the needed information, but everything you need should be in the events.

Answer (score 1):

event.toString() returns a string representation of the event object (actually will return a string related to the reference).

You can not use a cast to recreate the KeyEvent object.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt toString() contains all info on the object. You need serialization mechanism to recover the object. In Android, I would use JSONObject.